Pass Multiselect value in API
//Index.cshtml

<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="input-group mb-3 input-group-sm">
                <label class="input-group-text" for="filterMembers">Members</label>
                <select class="form-select filter" id="filterMembers" multiple>
                    <option value="">All</option>
                    @foreach (var items in Model.PersonnelList)
                    {
                            <option value="@items.id">@items.last_name, @items.first_name, @items.middle_name</option>
                    }
                </select>
                <label class="input-group-text small" for="filterLeaders">Leader/s</label>
                <select class="form-select filter" id="filterLeaders" multiple>
                    <option value="">All</option>
                    @foreach (var items in Model.PersonnelList)
                    {
                            <option value="@items.id">@items.last_name, @items.first_name, @items.middle_name</option>
                    }
                </select>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="clearFilters">Clear Filters</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
        <script src="~/js/team.js"></script>
}


//TeamController.cs

#region API CALLS
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAll(int?[] filterMembers, int?[] filterLeaders)
{
    var trMembersIds = filterMembers != null && filterMembers.Length > 0 ? _unitOfWork.AssignedMembers.GetAll()
        .Where(am => filterMembers.Contains(am.members_id))
        .Select(am => ap.team_id)
        .ToList() : new List<int>();
var trLeadersIds = filterLeaders != null && filterLeaders.Length > 0 ? _unitOfWork.AssignedLeaders.GetAll()
        .Where(am => filterLeaders.Contains(am.leader_id))
        .Select(am => ap.team_id)
        .ToList() : new List<int>();

    var iirList = _unitOfWork.TeamRecord.GetAll().Where(tr => (!filterMembers.Any() || trMembersIds.Contains(tr.id)) 
                                                                        && (!filterLeaders.Any() || trMembersIds.Contains(tr.id))
    .Select(tr => new
            {
                    tr.id,
                    // MORE CODES
            }).ToList();
    return Json(new { data = trList });
}
#endregion


//team.js

$(document).ready(function () {
    loadDataTable();

    $('.filter').on('change', function () {
        dataTable.ajax.reload();
    });

    $('#clearFilters').on('click', function () {
        $('.filter').val('');
        dataTable.ajax.reload();
    });
});


function loadDataTable() {
    dataTable = $('#tblDataTR').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/TR/GetAll",
            "type": "GET",
            "data": function (d) {
                d.filterMembers = $('#filterMembers').val() || [];
                d.filterLeaders = $('#filterLeaders').val() || [];
            },
            "dataSrc": "data"
        },
        "columns": [
            {
                // CODE FOR DISPLAYING COLUMNS
            }
        ]
    });
}

I have two multiple select for the filtration of data, but when I select the option, the datatable don't reload with the selected options. Its because the data is not passing in public IActionResult GetAll(int?[] filterMembers, int?[] filterLeaders), the two parameters are null. But when the select is not multiple, it runs just perfect with the data selected but I want is user can select multiple option like when you select "person1" and "person2" in filterMember select, all data involves "person1" and "person2" in one cell will be displayed.
PS. I'm new to coding.
